# What goes on in Amsterdam during New Year's Eve?

Tags: amsterdam, public-holidays, nightlife

What is Amsterdam like for New Year's Eve? What events are typical in this city?

Comment: We can't answer most of your final questions here on SE since we don't do recommendations and can't tell *you* what would be preferable for you. Therefore I've reduced the scope of the question to make it in topic for the site.

Answer (score 8):

Amsterdam, in fact all cities, most towns and many villages in the Netherlands, are having fireworks going all day and night, officially only till 3 AM but it is not unknown to hear them going from 27-12 to 3-1 almost continually.
At midnight almost every body will fire off fireworks, there will also be a main show like in other cities in the world. Everybody will likely go out on the street, enjoy the fireworks and then go on to a club or some such, or back home to celebrate with friends.

There is a strong tradition in the Netherlands to go to Amsterdam for all main feast days, to find parties and get into clubs.
But this night there are many 'closed doors' which means that you have to get a ticket well in advance or will not be allowed in.

There have been years with 'open' open air concerts and events, but those have basically stopped due to safety considerations. If there are still out of doors events, they will sell or give away tickets but without a ticket you will not get in.

I would suggest you to google Amsterdam oudejaarsavond 2016 (or new years eve but that will give you fewer results) and see if you can find tickets for events or clubs. Add your prefered style of music and you will likely find many.
I have not been to Amsterdam on NYE (nor on any of the main events) but friends who have been are very positive. (It is not the events, it is me.)
But if you can not get tickets for clubs or events, I would not bother coming, as far as I have heard, not much change getting into places without tickets.

Comment: +1, there's nothing better than a deeply informed answer

Comment: I spent last new year's eve in Amsterdam with my girlfriend (mainly for logistical reasons), and it was literally the worst. As a Dutch person I'm sort of used to the excessive orgy of fireworks, but Amsterdam was a whole new level and there have been a few times where I've been truly scared; people shooting rockets in crowd, *extremely* loud explosions that were far too close for comfort, etc. I had a ringing in my ears for weeks. YMMV but I found it the absolute worst of Amsterdam with none of the good parts.

Comment: There are news messages that fireworks are not allowed NYE midnight 21/22, the year before fireworks at midnight were not allowed in all of the country because of COVID 19, and the situation looks going the wrong way again for the upcoming winter.